# Disable element in Datalist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I disable a particular element in a datalist? It could either be just disabled (grayed out) our disappear completely. It just should not be selectable.

This is my approach, but that didn't help:

```
$("#browsers").find("Firefox").prop( "disabled", true );

<input list="browsers">

<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/oj8qdmw9/).

**UPDATE:**

I just noticed, that it doesn't work when I just cloned the datalist:

```
$("#mydiv").append($('.myclass').clone());
$("#browsers:eq(1)").find("[value='Firefox']").prop("disabled", true);
```

Any suggestions?

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/oj8qdmw9/1/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **[attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)** to get the option with value `Firefox`

```js
$("#browsers").find("[value='Firefox']").prop("disabled", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input list="browsers">

<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

---

**FYI :** `find("Firefox")` simply search for element with tag name as `Firefox`(eg : `<Firefox>`).

For more about [jQuery selectors visit here](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

---

**UPDATE :** As your question updated `#browsers:eq(1)` will select nothing.
First reason `id` selector only selects unique element, then `eq(1)` will try to select second element from the jQuery selected element( since index starts from `0` in `:eq()`) so which selects nothing. So just avoid the `eq()` this will solve the problem.

Also you can combine the selector like this

```
$("#browsers [value='Firefox']").prop("disabled", true);
```

---

**FYI :** Also you are just cloning the `input` tag which also using the existing datalist.